# HTML Video Code Seems Broken

Tags: html, website

I'm a new user on this site and just got my first IT internship right out of college. As one of my first tasks working for my new company I've started remaking the companies internal intranet. I didn't have a formal training with HTML at my school so I've been using Adobe Muse CC and doing my best to get the site up but now I've run into a problem adding the company's videos to the site.

After looking up a large amount of videos and consulting a friend I got this code to add to the site.

```
<video src="website_files\SF\mp4\sfretail.mp4" controls></video>
```

(Currently, it doesn't have the dimensions set but, I understand it enough that I can do it myself.)

The problem is that Muse assures me that the path is wrong and the video doesn't work. My friend took the same code to a Notepad++ and created a working video so we are both stumped as to what the problem is. Attached is a picture of the file path for the video. It is in a mp4 format and the website file itself is located in the "v1 Cigaret_Shopper" folder.

[image]

Comment: You'd posted this on meta.superuser.  It belongs on the main site. FTFY. Are you sure those things should be in the *desktop*?

Comment: Desktop? Oh, like I said, this is something that only I have been working on so I bring it home with me every night. We're a relativity small company so we don't really have a good network to store anything on. Thanks for the direction. I tried setting the tags but like I said I'm a bit new here so I'm sorry if I mess the posts up a bit. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a code issue pure and simple.  Muse should allow you to create a url to a file, through its interface, have you tried that?

Comment: I'm still a bit "green" in muse as well. I know how to navigate easy enough though. Any links I can look at?

Comment: Silly question, but where is the .html file?

Comment: Because Muse bundles everything together (like css and such) the html is actually part of the saved muse file.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, that may be an answer.  Is it possible for you to setup a youtube account for your company, then upload videos to that for use on your website?  Just make sure it's a generic username (a company email not tied to yours) and password, so other people can access it if they need to.

If that doesn't work, try looking at the answer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299347/how-do-i-embed-a-mp4-movie-into-my-html

It gives you the code and a website that can help.  Just a heads up, the code is specifically setup to allow different devices to play the same video in different formats.  So it's a bit lengthy because of that.  You can probably take out everything you don't need.

Edit:  I should point out, generally you want to make sure the source location starts in the root folder of the website.  So if the v1 cigaret_shopper is the root folder, then your source looks correct.  The controls however, may need to be set to `controls="controls"` instead.

Comment: That's a good idea and I very well may doing that but the problem is that the company is in Maine and the Internet speeds are exceedingly slow. This wouldn't be a problem if there wasn't 5-6 hours of video, (Cigar factory tours), that needed to be uploaded. Plus, Muse has a nifty tool for simple uploads like that.

( http://imgur.com/a/HIgrD )

The problem is that the videos are stored locally and need to be uploaded with the website. Thanks for the suggestion though, I might need to do something like that in the future.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a task that can run over the weekend :).  Also, i was just thinking.  If Muse keeps telling you the video path is wrong, have you tried the full path C:\users\*\desktop\...?  When it comes to troubleshooting, trying a few small changes like that doesn't hurt.  Also try putting the video in different folders (I.E. Root folder using src="video.mp4").